# Pyqt5 uic module not found

Tags: python, pyqt5, uic

I am trying to import loadui library in pycharm.I have already pip install pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools.But when I try to import loadui with `from PyQt5.uic import loadUi` this code it is giving me
`Unresolved reference 'LoadUi'` and `Cannot find reference 'uic' in '__init__.pyi'` errors.

How can i solve this ?

[image: Example]

Comment: Check that the module doesn't run. It could just be a warning. If Pycharm was running while installing you may need to restart Pycharm. If none of these work then try reinstalling PyQt5

Comment: I have the same problem (at least it seems so): an annoying "Cannot find reference 'uic' in '__init__.pyi'" "Problem", but code actually runs without any issue so I guess is a benign (but very annoying) warning. Installing pyqt5-tools has no visible effect. Does anyone have further hints?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to install PyQt5 tools.
Try this command:
pip install pyqt5-tools

Comment: pycharm is suggesting pyqt-stubs for more code sightings, that is buggy (do not install that binary) after doing 
pip install pyqt5-tools